# Sending List<Freight> to controller in ASP.net MVC using AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs

I need to send a JSON object which is a `List<Freight>` from the view to the controller.

How can I do this.

The class is:

```
public class Freights
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ListName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal PostPaidCost { get; set; }
    public string DisplayPrice { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Transport { get; set; }
    public string Instance { get; set; }
}
```

I tried out the following but it didn't work.

I need to send `List<Freights>` which is stored in `Freights` in the below code.

```
$http.post('/Customization/FreightItems_update?Freights=' 
     + Freights + '&CustomerGuid=' + CustomerGuid).success(function (result) {
        ...
});
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult FreightItems_update(List<Freights> Freights, Guid CustomerGuid)
{
}
```

I even tried to get the data as object and cast it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// _Freights =  aray of Freights 
//_CustomerGuid = CustomerGuid

var myObject =  {
                          Freights: _Freights,
                          CustomerGuid: _CustomerGuid                            
                        };

 $http.post('/Customization/FreightItems_update', myObject)
        .then(
          function () { alert('ok')}
        , function () {alert('can't post') }
 );
```

option 2

```
 $http.post('/Customization/FreightItems_update',
 {Freights: _Freights,  CustomerGuid: _CustomerGuid})
            .then(
              function () { alert('ok')}
            , function () {alert('can't post') }
     );
```

Comment: How can I access `myObject` inside the action method?

Comment: your action 'FreightItems_update'  will recognise that myObject contains Freights and CustomerGuid, so you dont have to worry about myObject you can access Freights , CustomerGuid in your action

Comment: My question is, when we are sending parameters you work with those variables, here how can I use the myObject?

Comment: @RandomUser  myObject is only wrapper for your data you can use option2 if you preffer

Comment: forgive me if I am dumb, but I need to know how can I use the `myObject` in the controller, for example in my question, imagine that I do get the list as intended I would use it as `Freights[0].Name` in the action method.

Comment: @RandomUser please test if your create proper array of `Freights` and `CustomerGuid` in your js you will be able to access first `Freights` in this way  `Freights[0].Name`

Comment: again pardon me I am talking about the MVC controller not AngularJS controller

Comment: @RandomUser exactly have to test it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58336/discussion-between-sylwester-and-randomuser).